# Arduino String Parsing issue

Tags: c++, string, windows, parsing, arduino

I have a problem, I am sending some data from a PC C++ app with this structure from a visual studio app:

```
puerto1.WriteLine(rpm + ";" + gea + ":" + speed + ";;" + fuel + "::" + boost + ";;;" + rtemp + ":::" + atemp + ";;;;" + gas + "::::" + brk + ";;;;;");
```

And then on the Arduino, I parse it in 9 different strings and when I want to display it on a screen it reports the problem of the pic attached.
It works correctly sometimes, but it stopped working correctly a few days ago and it haven't returned to work properly, it should print the strings indepently like:
XXX
XXX
XXX
XXX
XXX
Not  like the image.

Arduino code:

```
#include <UTFTGLUE.h>
UTFTGLUE myGLCD(0, A2, A1, A3, A4, A0);
extern uint8_t BigFont[];
String command;

String part1;
String part2;
String part3;
String part4;
String part5;
String part6;
String part7;
String part8;
String part9;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myGLCD.InitLCD();
  myGLCD.setFont(BigFont);
  myGLCD.clrScr();

  myGLCD.setColor(255, 255, 255);
  myGLCD.setBackColor(0, 0, 0);
  myGLCD.print("RPMs", 1, 10);
  myGLCD.print("Gear", 1, 40);
  myGLCD.print("Speed", 1, 70);
  myGLCD.print("Fuel", 1, 100);
  myGLCD.print("Boost", 1, 130);
  myGLCD.print("Asphalt Temp", 1, 160);
  myGLCD.print("Air Temp", 1, 190);
  myGLCD.print("Gas", 1, 220);
  myGLCD.print("Brake", 1, 250);
  myGLCD.print("Engine Brake", 1, 280);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    char c = Serial.read();

    if (c == '\n') {
      parseCommand(command);
      command = "";
    } else {
      command += c;
    }

  }

  myGLCD.setColor(255, 255, 255);
  myGLCD.setBackColor(0, 0, 0);

  myGLCD.printNumI(val1, 5, 20);
  myGLCD.print(part2, 5, 50);
  myGLCD.printNumI(val3, 5, 80);
  myGLCD.print(part4, 5, 110);
  myGLCD.print(part5, 5, 140);
  myGLCD.print(part6, 5, 170);
  myGLCD.print(part7, 5, 200);
  myGLCD.print(part8, 5, 230);
  myGLCD.print(part9, 5, 260);
  myGLCD.print(part10, 5, 290);
}

void parseCommand(String com) {

  part1 = com.substring(0, com.indexOf(";"));
  part2 = com.substring(com.indexOf(";") + 1, com.indexOf(":"));
  part3 = com.substring(com.indexOf(":") + 1, com.indexOf(";;"));
  part4 = com.substring(com.indexOf(";;") + 2, com.indexOf("::"));
  part5 = com.substring(com.indexOf("::") + 2, com.indexOf(";;;"));
  part6 = com.substring(com.indexOf(";;;") + 3, com.indexOf(":::"));
  part7 = com.substring(com.indexOf(":::") + 3, com.indexOf(";;;;"));
  part8 = com.substring(com.indexOf(";;;;") + 4, com.indexOf("::::"));
  part9 = com.substring(com.indexOf("::::") + 4, com.indexOf(";;;;;"));

  int val1 = part1.toInt();
  int val3 = part3.toInt();

}
```

[problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whfEa.jpg)

Comment: `val1` and `val2` are declared locally in `ParseCommand()`. I'm surprised that it compiles, `myGLCD.printNumI(val1, 5, 20);` shouldn't know about the existence of `val1`

Comment: I have declared globaly the `val1` and `val3` variables and it does the same

Comment: In your C++ code, try to print incoming serial to console. Then in your Arduino code, at the start of the `parseCommand()` function, print the command string with `Serial.print(com);` Then you can se if the command is received correctly.

Comment: You declared them globally, but did you remove declaration from function? If not, local `val1` is different than global `val1`.

Comment: Yes, i deleted it from the function @Yksisarvinen